# setting symfony for local development on herkou

Tags: symfony, heroku

I am trying to set up my symfony 2.8 app for local development.(Following - https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/heroku.html)

Added In proc file
web: bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/

Error
bin/sh: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory

Also note , composer.phar config bin-dir is bin

Anyone who can share how they resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you tried letting heroku create the Procfile itself? I think lately it was smart enough to work out the root of the Symfony project.

If that doesn't work, maybe that's not the right path, try:

```
echo 'web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 web/' > Procfile
```

If none of those work, I'd rather use the heroku information on how to deploy your Symfony app, have a look at this and see if it helps:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony

Comment: I have code already with me locally(git branch clone) which is attached to heroku now I am trying to connect locally to heroku for development and not able to connect because there is no heroku-php-apche2 file or directory.

Comment: Can you read above and try what I first suggested and let heroku create teh Procfile for you? Try to deploy without creating a Procfile.